# Problem while copying the columns based on the condition

Tags: excel, vba

I want to copy only C and E columns values, but it is also copying D.

I have written a code, That will copy the columns C and it corresponding elements of column E from "REF" sheet, when the E values are in between 0 to 60. Then it will copy it to the "Cost" sheet. But it is copying the C, D and E values also.  Please help me to solve the problem. Attached the code below

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

lastRow = Worksheets("REF").Range("E" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

For r = 2 To lastRow

    If Worksheets("REF").Range("E" & r).Value <= 60 And Worksheets("REF").Range("E" & r).Value >= 0 Then
    
        Worksheets("REF").Range("C" & r & ":E" & r).Copy
        Worksheets("Cost").Activate
        lastRowSheet1 = Worksheets("Cost").Range("C" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
        Worksheets("Cost").Range("C" & lastRowSheet1 + 1).Select
        ActiveSheet.Paste
        End If
        Next r

End Sub
```

for datas refer the image

[image]

When the button clicked it is started printing from the next cell where it printed recently

Comment: It's copying D because you coded that. `Worksheets("REF").Range("C" & r & ":E" & r).Copy` means range C:E and D is just in the middle.

Answer (score 1):

### Copy Cells With Criteria

**Tips**

- Use `Option Explicit`.
- Avoid using `Activate` and `Select` and various flavors of them.
- Use variables.

A Quick Fix

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
    
    ' Define workbook.
    Dim wb As Workbook
    Set wb = ThisWorkbook
    ' Define worksheets.
    Dim src As Worksheet
    Set src = wb.Worksheets("REF")
    Dim tgt As Worksheet
    Set tgt = wb.Worksheets("Cost")
    ' Define last rows.
    Dim srcLastRow As Long
    srcLastRow = src.Range("E" & src.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    Dim tgtLastRow As Long
    tgtLastRow = tgt.Range("C" & src.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    
    Dim r As Long
    Dim NewRow As Long
    NewRow = tgtLastRow
    
    For r = 2 To srcLastRow
        If src.Range("E" & r).Value >= 0 And src.Range("E" & r).Value <= 60 Then
            NewRow = NewRow + 1
            src.Range("C" & r).Copy tgt.Range("C" & NewRow)
            src.Range("E" & r).Copy tgt.Range("D" & NewRow) ' Not sure if D or E
        End If
    Next r
    
End Sub
```

Comment: Hey !     Thats help me a lot. but there is  another problem. While copying the Column "E". VBA program copies the formula not values. I want only the values not the formula. Can you please help me with that

Comment: PasteSpecial xlPasteValues, How do I use this there?

Comment: PasteSpecial is too slow, you use `tgt.Range("C" & NewRow).Value = src.Range("C" & r).Value` and  `tgt.Range("D" & NewRow).Value = src.Range("E" & r).Value`.

Comment: If you insist on PasteSpecial, because you have more [options](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.xlpastetype), then the src... parts are in one line, and the tgt... parts are in the next line. The tgt...parts are e.g.: `tgt.Range("C" & NewRow).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues`.